# JQuery tablesorting code not working (no plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I'm displaying a table with AJAX in my website. I wrote a JQuery code for sorting my table when it's send via AJAX and a `<th>`-tag is clicked. (I don't want to use a plugin. No, really, I don't want to use a plugin!)

This is my code:

PHP (index.php):

```
<form action="query.php" method="get">
    <input type="search" name="query" autofocus="true" autocomplete="off" list="products">
    <datalist id="products">
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM products;";

            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

            while ($product = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<option value=\"" . $product["productname"] . "\">" . $product["price"] . " $</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </datalist>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
<div class="result" align="center"></div>
```

PHP (query.php):

```
<?php
    include_once "connection.php";

    $query = trim($_GET["query"]);
    $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $query);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE productname LIKE '%$query%' ORDER BY productname;";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $result_no = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($result_no > 0) {
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Product</th>";
        echo "<th>Price</th>";
        echo "<th>Quantity</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";

        while ($product = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr class=\"table\"><td align=\"left\">" . $product["productname"] . "</td><td align=\"right\">" . $product["price"] . " $</td><td align=\"right\">" . $product["quantity"] . "</td></tr>";
        }

        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "<tfoot>";

        if ($result_no == 1) {
            echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\" align=\"center\">" . $result_no . " product found." . "</td></tr>";
        } else {
            echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\" align=\"center\">" . $result_no . " product found." . "</td></tr>";
        }

        echo "</tfoot>";
        echo "</table>";

    } elseif ($result_no <= 0) {
        echo "<p>No products found.</p>";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("form").on("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: this.method,
            url: this.action,
            data: form.serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $("div.result").html(data);

                $("th").on("click", function() {
                    var column = $(this).index();
                    var tbody = $("tbody");
                    var rows = tbody.find("tr");
                    var dir = $(this).data("dir") || -1;
                    dir *= -1;

                    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
                        var aVal = $($(a).find("td")[column]).text().toLowerCase();
                        var bVal = $($(b).find("td")[column]).text().toLowerCase();
                        return aVal > bVal ? 1 * dir : aVal < bVal ? -1 * dir : 0;
                    });

                    $(this).data("dir", dir);

                    tbody.empty();
                    $(rows).appendTo(tbody);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The connection.php is for connecting to my database. I use MySQL and PHPMyAdmin. My tables are 'users' for login data and 'products' for the shop products.

My Problem: The first line of the table is alway sorted at the wrong place.

Comment: What is data? If you're not using tablesorter plugin then please remove that tag.

Comment: What is not working? What is your expected output? We have no simple way of running this against actual data, so it's impossible to tell what's broken about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This topic is closed. Here's the code I was looking for:

1. JavaScript: https://jsfiddle.net/tf4e97w6/#&togetherjs=TGIj8qdzUO
2. jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/15ke8Lqv/#&togetherjs=DACQV5mE9F
3. Code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("th").on("click", function() {
    var column = $(this).index();
    var table = $("table");
    var tbody = table.find("tbody");
    var rows = tbody.find("tr");
    var dir = $(this).data("dir") || -1;
    dir *= -1;
    $(this).siblings().data("dir", -1);

    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
      var aVal = $($(a).find("td")[column]).html().toLowerCase().trim();
      var bVal = $($(b).find("td")[column]).html().toLowerCase().trim();

      if ($.isNumeric(aVal.charAt()) && $.isNumeric(bVal.charAt())) {
        aVal = parseFloat(aVal);
        bVal = parseFloat(bVal);
      }

      return aVal > bVal ? 1 * dir : aVal < bVal ? -1 * dir : 0;
    });

    $(this).data("dir", dir);

    tbody.empty();
    $(rows).appendTo(table);
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  color: #cc1100;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tfoot,
thead {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

th:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <caption>
    <h1>Tablesorter</h1>
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$160</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>March</td>
      <td>$240</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>April</td>
      <td>$160</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Sum: $710</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

With kind regards,
Felix Rewer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in javascript [sort](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) function.

1. I extracted the relevant sort code from your example
2. I grabbed a sample table from [w3cschools](https://www.w3schools.com/default.asp)
3. I modified the `js` to store the sorted direction in the header cell.
4. I implemented a `compare` function (see linked sort documentation).
5. I replaced the `tbody` when the sort was complete.

EDIT: changed out HTML, added functionality to function to enable numeric sorting and not just alphabetically. **Note the `number` class and the new `if` in the sort function**

```js
$("th").on("click", function() {
  var column = $(this).index();
  var numeric = $(this).hasClass("number"); //this class has been sprinkled to identify numeric sort.
  var bdy = $(this).closest("table").find("tbody");
  var rows = bdy.find("tr");
  var dir = $(this).data("dir") || -1; //default direction is desc
  dir *= -1; //reverse the stored direction
  rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aVal = $($(a).find("td")[column]).text().toLowerCase(); //get the text from one row
    var bVal = $($(b).find("td")[column]).text().toLowerCase(); //get the text from row 2
    if (numeric) {  //added to handle numeric columns
      aVal = parseFloat(aVal);
      bVal = parseFloat(bVal);
    }
    return aVal > bVal ? 1 * dir : aVal < bVal ? -1 * dir : 0; // note the dir value to change direction
  }); //sort the rows by the column content
  bdy.empty(); //empty the body
  $(rows).appendTo(bdy); //put the rows back
  $(this).data("dir", dir); //log the direction
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="table">
      <th class="table">Product</th>
      <th class="table number">Price</th>
      <th class="table number">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table">
      <td align="left" class="table">Chainsaw</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">60.00 $</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table">
      <td align="left" class="table">Hammer</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">24.99 $</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table">
      <td align="left" class="table">Nails (25 per Box)</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">9.99 $</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table">
      <td align="left" class="table">Screwdriver</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">29.99 $</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table">
      <td align="left" class="table">Screws (25 per Box)</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">15.00 $</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">26</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="table">
      <td colspan="3" align="center" class="table">5 products found.</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to be working. If I run this code the first row is wrong. Maybe it's because of the dollar signs in my table?

Comment: Felix if you had provided any HTML, then we might be able to help you with the issue.  This just compares the cells alphabetically.

Comment: I added my code. PS: I modified your code, not to make it more useful, but just to look nice for me.

Comment: @FelixRewer, please include a sample rendered table, your question was updated with your PHP.  I believe that the PHP is not your problem but the HTML that comes out the other end.

Answer (score 0):

> @FelixRewer, please include a sample rendered table, your question was updated with your PHP. I believe that the PHP is not your problem but the HTML that comes out the other end.

Yes, maybe you're right. So here's a code snippet with the output of query.php and the JQuery tablesorter (I also added my styles, I don't think it's relevant, but if yes, here it is.):

```js
$("th").on("click", function() {
  var column = $(this).index();
  var table = $("table");
  var tbody = table.find("tbody");
  var rows = tbody.find("tr");
  var dir = $(this).data("dir") || -1;
  dir *= -1;

  rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aVal = $($(a).find("td")[column]).text().toLowerCase().trim();
    var bVal = $($(b).find("td")[column]).text().toLowerCase().trim();
    return aVal > bVal ? 1 * dir : aVal < bVal ? -1 * dir : 0;
  });

  $(this).data("dir", dir);

  tbody.empty();
  $(rows).appendTo(table);
});
```

```css
.table {
  margin: 3vmax;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="table">
      <th class="table">Product</th>
      <th class="table">Price</th>
      <th class="table">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table">
      <td align="left" class="table">Chainsaw</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">60.00 $</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table">
      <td align="left" class="table">Hammer</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">24.99 $</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table">
      <td align="left" class="table">Nails (25 per Box)</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">9.99 $</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table">
      <td align="left" class="table">Screwdriver</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">29.99 $</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table">
      <td align="left" class="table">Screws (25 per Box)</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">15.00 $</td>
      <td align="right" class="table">26</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="table">
      <td colspan="3" align="center" class="table">5 products found.</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

And yes I have the same problem here. I've tested a lot with my code and I think maybe the first line gets sorted at the wrong place, because of the `<tfoot>`, but that's just an assumption.

Comment: I updated my answer to include ability to sort numerically and not just alphabetically.